# Comodín en la ruta para el Router de Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Actualmente tengo una aplicación en Angular 12. El enrutamiento funciona correctamente

Este es el código del `app.component-routing.module`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('@modules/authentication/authentication.module')
    .then( m => m.AuthenticationModule )
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: () => import('@modules/home/home.module')
    .then( m => m.HomeModule )
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Funciona perfecto con estas rutas

```
localhost:4200/login
localhost:4200/app/dashboard
localhost:4200/app/users/juan-perez
```

Necesito poner un parámetro antes de cualquier fragmento de ruta

```
localhost:4200/company-foo/login
localhost:4200/company-foo/app/dashboard
localhost:4200/company-foo/app/users/juan-perez
```

Esto para que cuando haga una consulta, me traiga solo la información que respecta a la `company-foo`

Dado el requerimiento de negocio, en el mismo sistema debe ser capaz de diferenciar la información dependiendo de este fragmento de ruta.

```
localhost:4200/company-bar/login
localhost:4200/company-bar/app/dashboard
localhost:4200/company-bar/app/users/juan-perez
```

Intenté poner ese comodín así

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: () => import('@modules/authentication/authentication.module')
    .then( m => m.AuthenticationModule )
  },
  {
    path: '**/app',
    loadChildren: () => import('@modules/home/home.module')
    .then( m => m.HomeModule )
  },

];
```

Ahora ya no me aparece nada, se queda en blanco la app. ¿Cómo podría agregar ese fragmento de ruta que NO SIEMPRE ES EL MISMO?

Answer (score 1):

Agrégalo como un parámetro en la ruta:

```
{
    path: ':section/app',
    loadChildren: () => import('@modules/home/home.module')
    .then( m => m.HomeModule )
}
```

El segmento antes de `/app` se guardará en el parámetro `section`.